# AttributeError : module 'module.modulename' has no attribute 'register'

Tags: python

Apologies everyone. Begining out Python and Flask.

I'm trying to add all my routes to a separate routes.py file.
Below is my folder structure.

```
 - appfolder
    - routes
        __init__.py (empty file)
        routes.py
    - app.py
```

**routes.py contents**

```
from flask import Blueprint

routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__)


@routes.route('/')
def index():
    return 'index'

@routes.route('backend/login')
def backendlogin():
    return 'backend login'
```

**app.py contents**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from routes import routes


app = None
db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    global app, db

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['FLASK_DEBUG'] = True

    # Register Routes
    app.register_blueprint(routes)

    return app


__all__ = (app, db, create_app)
```

When I try to run `flask run` in the terminal I get thrown the below error.

> AttributeError: module 'routes.routes' has no attribute 'register'

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been stuck for a few hours on this.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually importing the blueprint from routes.py, you're importing the script containing the blueprint hence the error message

> AttributeError: **module** 'routes.routes' has no attribute 'register'

change this

`from routes import routes`

to

`from routes.routes import routes`